# Unique Ordered Data Structure

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, computer-science

What is the optimal data structure to use, knowing that the data to be stored consists of a fixed number of unique values, where order matters? In particular, I'm trying to optimally store the state of a deck of 52 cards, where each card is represented by a number from 1 to 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only concern is expressing the permutation (wrt the *natural* order), you could choose a [factorial number system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), which is the smallest thinkable representation for a permutation.

BTW: this is not a very *practical* solution; 52! is approximately 8E67 ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't you only need 52 factoradic digits though?

Comment: Also, 52! values can be expressed in 225 bits, which is less than the 312 bits required to make an array of 52 6-bit values.

Comment: I count 257 bits (21*6+16*5+8*4+4*3+2*2+1) , this if you put each radix-position  into a minimal number of bits. This wasts some code space, but make extraction of the digit_at_position_x relatively easy. (no bignum division needed)

Answer (score 1):

A an array/vector will do this nicely for you.

You have a fixed number of objects (cards) that you can identify with an integer without gaps between the possible integer values.  This allows you to use a data structure that occupies a contiguous block of memory and allows direct access based on the value (indexing), and the access uses the natural ordering of integer values -- this fits an array/vector perfectly

Comment: An array is certainly the _easiest_ solution, I'm just curious as to the most optimal solution, since I want to store the order of the values without storing the values themselves.

Comment: Easiest and optimal - occupes the least amount of memory, allows O(1) access to the elements, you do not want to delete/insert elements -- this is exactly what an array/vector offers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the uniqueness in the set you could use a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) in Java
and I expect other languages / libraries have similar

Answer (score 0):

Given that order matters and there's a fixed number of elements, then simply use an array of cards, something like this:

```
Card[] cards = new Card[52];
```

Just make sure to index from 0 to 51, in most programming languages it'd be simpler than indexing from 1 to 52.

Comment: See my comment on "Attila"'s answer for why that isn't the solution.

Comment: @taktoa If you only want to store the order of the values, then use an `int[]` of 52 positions for storing the indexes of the cards in the `Card[]`, and just be careful with the indexes (it'd be easier to just index your cards from 0 to 51). Either way, the optimal data structure here is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a single 226 bit integer plus a numbering scheme for mapping the deck into its possible orderings.

[Storing a message in a deck of cards](http://jerde.net/peter/cards/cards.html)

[Detailed explanation of the above link](http://jerde.net/peter/cards/explanation.html)

[key-deck](http://junkcode.erisian.com.au/key-deck) (simple Python code)